# Android - Broadcast Receiver for bluetooth has 20 sec delay

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to write a simple app, which starts playing music from Spotify after it detects the connection to the specific Bluetooth headset.
Code down below is working, but Broadcast Receiver is activated after 20 sec. Is it possible to do it instantly after connecting, or should I use other methods ? I saw something about BluetoothAdapter, but I don't understand how to use it.

**Service.java**

```
public class Service extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Toast.makeText(context,"Teraz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (device.getName().equals("MDR-XB650BT")) {
            String spotifyPackageName = "com.spotify.music";
            String viewAction = Intent.ACTION_VIEW;
            String spotifyUriString = "spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DXasrwGQyyDvl" + ":play";
            Uri spotifyUri = Uri.parse(spotifyUriString);
            Intent spotifyIntent = new Intent(viewAction, spotifyUri);
            //I found this in other questions, but it doesn't work for me
            spotifyIntent.setFlags(FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND | FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND | FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
            spotifyIntent.setPackage(spotifyPackageName);
            if (spotifyIntent != null) {
                context.startActivity(spotifyIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pawe.bluetooth_service"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">


    <receiver android:name=".Service">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".hello">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```